# How to achieve vertical div alignment in unique situation?

Tags: html, css

Go to [my blog](http://roseannebarr.tumblr.com) and please tell me how to achieve vertical alignment :( My situation truly is different and I need help :)

The reason this is so difficult is because holder is the div that contains everything, outer are the icons at the bottom, and tooltip are the divs that pop up. I need tooltip to be vertically aligned but they are actually below outer. Each icon is connected to their post so you can't keep them all in one div.

Comment: Having empty `<div>` s all with the same ID over and over again is not good.

Comment: I know, the entire page is based on error but it functions in all browsers and its THE ONLY WAY to do this without using javascript so why not. (The downside is it's near impossible to add any animation.)

Comment: Oh, P.S: They aren't empty it is how Tumblr works. What is actually in those is their content blocks that YOU cant see.

Comment: Why not is because the code is invalid and not semantically correct. You should really considering finding another way to achieve your results. Web standards exist for a reason.

Comment: Actually, the stuff you can't see looks like this:
{block:Photo}
    <img id="block" src="http://static.tumblr.com/ux4v5bf/UJuleohws/photo.png">
    <div class="notes">{block:NoteCount}&nbsp;{NoteCount}{/block:NoteCount} <img id="heart" src="http://static.tumblr.com/ux4v5bf/qgLleoqlx/heart.png">
    </br>
    {MonthNumber} {DayOfMonth} {ShortYear}
    </div>
    <div id="tooltip">

{LinkOpenTag}<center><img id="photo" src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" /></center>{LinkCloseTag}
{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}

    </div>
{/block:Photo}
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
#holder{
     bottom:50%;
}
```

Comment: I need to align ToolTip (the popup)